# how to let python consider links in a list as a single item

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this script:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

base = ("https://www.inforge.net/xi/")

for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'}):
    links = (tag.get('href'))
    final = base + links

print (final[0])
```

which takes every link of the topics in [this page](https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/).

The problem is that when I `print(final[0])` the output is:

```
h
```

instead of the entire link. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: are you expecting base and links to be tuples? The parenthesis make it look like you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` has a type of `str`, as such, indexing it in position `0` will result in the first character of the `url` getting printed, specifically `h`.

You either need to print all of `final` if you're using it as a `str`:

```
print(final)
```

or, if you must have a `list`, make `final` a `list` in the `for` loop by enclosing it in square brackets `[]`:

```
final = [base + links]
```

then `print(final[0])` will print the first element of the `list` as you'd expect.

---

As @Bryan pointed out and I just noticed, it seems like you might be confused about the usage of `()` in Python. Without a comma `,` inside the `()` they do absolutely nothing. If you add the comma, it turns them into `tuples` (not `lists`, lists use square brackets `[]`).

So:

```
base = ("https://www.inforge.net/xi/")
```

results in `base` referring to a value of `str` type while:

```
base = ("https://www.inforge.net/xi/", )
# which can also be written as:
base =  "https://www.inforge.net/xi/",
```

results in `base` referring to a value of `tuple` type with a single element.

The same applies for the name `links`:

```
links = (tag.get('href'))   # 'str'
links = (tag.get('href'), ) # 'tuple'
```

If you change `links` and `base` to be tuples then `final` is going to end up as a 2 element `tuple` after `final = base + links` is executed. So, in this case you should join the elements inside the tuple during your `print` call:

```
print ("".join(final))  # takes all elements in final and joins them together
```